unable to verify the first certificate in node js
I'm working on mobile app using React Native with Expo, everything is fine after two days,then when I running npm start an error like this appears
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/50.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (F:\AminosApps\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1501:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

I did reinstall the expo-cli with npm i -g expo-cli  but the install process is stuck in the middle.

Try using npx expo start

Thanks for your answer @Michael , I have tried using that too, but the error still same

Can you post your node version and your OpenSSL version?
Try export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && expo start

Thanks @MichaelBahl,  turns out my antivirus is blocking the SSL. I turn it off and the expo run well

I once experienced the same problem, I solved it by giving SSL access permission in the anti-virus that I used. try resetting your SSL protector settings.
then delete package-lock.json and node_modules and restart npm install then restart npm start
